# no app bar and drawer in other activity except main

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

main activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        initNavigationDrawer();

    }

    public void initNavigationDrawer() {

    }
```

no activity in mobile_form activity

```
public class mobile_form extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view= findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mobile_form);
}
```

style.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[Use Toolbar across all activities (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661981/use-toolbar-across-all-activities-android)

I tried it but I think navigtion bar is there because the size is changed after adding drawer layout to my second activity but is shows blank white color there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Toolbar across all activities (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661981/use-toolbar-across-all-activities-android)

Comment: no i cant find answer i tried it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have action bar in another activity, because you do not set it in another activity. This part of code should be added to each onCreate method:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    initNavigationDrawer();
```

Because by default, you removed ActionBar from any activity by using:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

in your application code.

P.S. Btw, this part of code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Should be also added to each activity layout file, if you wish to use toolbar at that activities.

P.S.S. You should read [Adding the App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) and [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) tutorials from google.

Comment: still error E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arun4fms.efix/com.example.arun4fms.efix.mobile_form}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Yep, you didn't create layout properly and didn't init NavigationDrawer. Please read updated answer

Comment: wait sir let me try

Comment: app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"